# How can I bootstrap Jersey REST service server?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've been thrown into a project that is basically just a REST service an provides some functionality to web clients. However, I can't see any bootstrapping going on yet for the services - like not at all..

In particular I have to setup the file system for the server and its services. Therefore I am looking for a way to get control of the web application as the server is booting up and *before* it is loading the REST resources:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;

@Path("/")
@Singleton
public class EnrichmentResource {
    // ...
}
```

How can I do that? I can only find such [simple examples](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) where a REST Controller gets defined but no bootstrapping examples.

Comment: do you have a class that extends ResourceConfig ?

Comment: @vincent I am starting to realize that the guy who wrote that bypassed the bootstrapping by simply making things `static` such that they're loaded as the application starts O_o I have no other explanation for that what I see.. but no, it appears no class in the whole project extends ResourceConfig.

Comment: @displayname, I would recomment to start with RestEasy http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/ and look on `Alternative REST Service Registration` topic in that page

Comment: @TheCoder This shows just how to initialize the resources manually. Is there a way to get the resources being initialized automatically but *before* that happens just make some other initializational stuff?

Comment: @displayname, you mean like `Listeners`..? Elaborate the Pre initialization stuff if possible..

Comment: @TheCoder Well e.g. we have tasks that can be serialized. Before the server actually starts to do his job I want to take over control and see if those jobs are actually still fine or if they cannot be deserialized due to an update or something like that. I also want to do some basic checking on the file system e.g. if certain configuration files are actually present and if not either create a default file or log and error and shutdown the whole thing again.

Comment: @TheCoder What I need is just the entry point of the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "pre-entry" part of JAX-RS per se.  However, in any JEE application you can always define a WebListener:

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println( "context initialized" );
    }
}
```

The contextInitialized() method will be called before anything is called into your REST services.  Remember that JAX-RS is still built on top of the servlet framework.

Comment: This is working for me! Exactly what I was looking for - I hope this actually is the right place to do what I want but at least now I can do it *when* I want :D